# Trigger a function on multiple elements on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I’m trying to trigger Odometer.js on several figures on scroll. Code is wrong and I think i’m gonna cry.. 2 hours and nothing : Uncaught TypeError: this.el.appendChild is not a function...

Please help. Thanks.

html:

```
  <h2 class="odometre" chiffre-cle="2000">0</h2>
  <h2 class="odometre" chiffre-cle="2000">0</h2>
  <h2 class="odometre" chiffre-cle="2000">0</h2>
```

javascript:

```
var y = $(window).height(); 
var coord = y / 2;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > coord){
        $(".odometre").each(function(){
            var el = $(this);
            var chiffre = el.attr("chiffre-cle");
            od = new Odometer({
                el: el,
                value: 0,
                format: 'd',
                animation: 'ease',
                duration: 400
            });
            od.update(chiffre);
        })
    }
    else {
    }
});
```

Comment: could you post the html? what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like Odometer.js is needing a HTMLElement not a jQuery Object, in order to fix that you should remove your `$()` wrapper from `this` right here:

```
var el = $(this);
var chiffre = el.attr("chiffre-cle");
```

to make it look like:

```
var el = this;
var chiffre = $(el).attr("chiffre-cle");
```

Comment: Hi Santiago, try it without success :/ Now : Uncaught TypeError: el.attr is not a function